# Why is this function not deleting nodes?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes, free

I'm a beginner programmer just starting to get my hands dirty with linked lists.

I'm currently trying to figure out a function that deletes a song (node) from a "playlist" (linked list.) Each node has 3 data points, 2 strings (artist and title) and 1 integer (release year.) Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Function:

```
struct Node *borrow_song(struct Node *pointer) {
  
  struct Node *temp = pointer;
  char response[40];
  struct Node *remove;

  printf("Which song do you want to borrow? (title): ");
  scanf(" %s", response);

  
  while(temp != NULL) {
    
    remove = temp;
    
    if (strcmp(response, temp->title) == 0) {
      
      printf("\nSuccess! %s is in the list. Borrowing..\n", response);
      
      free(remove); // I have a feeling this isn't how you properly free a node.
      remove = NULL;
      
        return 0;
      
      }
      
    else 

      temp = temp->next;
    
    }

    printf("%s was not in the list... Try again.", response);

    return 0;

  }
```

Driver:

```
switch....

case 4:
        borrow_song(head);
        printf("\nNew list:\n\n");
        print_list(head);
```

Node creation function from a generous person on here (creates node from .txt file)

```
struct Node *read_node(FILE *inputp) {

  struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    
  if (temp != NULL &&  fscanf(inputp, "%39s%39s%d", &temp->name, &temp->title, &temp->year) == 3) {

    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    return temp;

    } 

  else {

    free(temp);
    return NULL;

    }
}
```

And lastly, the driver for that:

```
while ((node = read_node(inputp)) != NULL) {
    
    if (!head) {
      
      head = tail = node;
      
        } 
    
    else {
      
      node->prev = tail;
      tail = tail->next = node;
      
        }
    }
```

This is the input file:

1. Rachmaninov Concerto_No_2 1999
2. Mozart Symphony_No_41 2000
3. Vivaldi The_Seasons 2003
4. Beethoven Symphony_No_5 1994
5. Bach Toccatas 2005

This is the console output:

Which song do you want to borrow? (title): Toccatas

1. Success! Toccatas is in the list. Borrowing..
2. 
3. New list:
4. 
5. Rachmaninov, Concerto_No_2, 1999
6. Mozart, Symphony_No_41, 2000
7. Vivaldi, The_Seasons, 2003
8. Beethoven, Symphony_No_5, 1994
9. `ʣt, Toccatas, 2005

Still working on pointers, I guess we all start somewhere :P

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you are going to get downvoted because you did not post a testable program, just snippets

Comment: strong suggestion: stop writing code for a moment  and learn to use your debugger, the basics will take 10 to 15 minutes. SO cannot debug it for you without a complete program

Comment: `free(remove)` is the last step, you have to unlink it from the list, the previous link needs to change its next pointer, the next link needs to change its prior pointer

Comment: Also turn your compiler warnings up. Any compiler worth its salt should catch what is almost certainly a type mismatch here: `"%39s%39s%d", &temp->name, &temp->title`, where the `&` are not needed (assuming the `name` and `title` members are of type `char [40]`, or equivalent). In any case, for your best bet at a complete answer, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And the result of your function should be used; not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlink the node by setting the previous node's next pointer to point to the node after the one being removed.  If the node to remove is the first node in the list, there is no previous node, so you need to allow for the head of the list to change, probably by always returning the pointer to the head element (which appears to be what was intended if you look at the return type!).

The most uniform way to do this is to keep a `Node **next_ptr` initially set to `&pointer`.  In the loop, set `Node *temp = *next_ptr` and see if you want to remove the `temp` node.  If so, set `*next_ptr = temp->next`, free `temp` and return `pointer`.  If not, set `next_ptr = &temp->next` and go around the loop again.  If `temp == NULL`, then you didn't find the node, and should return `pointer`.  In this way, if the node to remove is the first one, you will have updated `pointer`, otherwise you will have updated the previous node's `next`.  Either way, you always return `pointer`, which will always be the head element.